# whats is the better way to represent my yaml file

Tags: java, yaml

is there a better way to represent below yaml file so it will be easier to read and use ? currently i need to create bean for each one and i want to know if there is a better way to represent my yaml file so i wont need such huge structure

```
product:
  productId:
    instructions:
    exclude: false
    exists: true
    equals: false
    isSimple: true
  alternateId:
    instructions:
      exclude: true
      exists: false
      equals: false
      isSimple: true

productTotalPrice:
  priceType:
    exclude: false
    exists: true
    equals: true
    isSimple: true
  recurringChargePeriod:
    exclude: false
    exists: true
    equals: true
    isSimple: true
  taxRate:
    exclude: false
    exists: true
    equals: true
    isSimple: true
  price:
    exclude: false
    exists: true
    equals: true
    isSimple: false
  standalonePrice:
    exclude: false
    exists: true
    equals: true
    isSimple: false
  finalPrice:
    exclude: false
    exists: true
    equals: true
    isSimple: false


standalonePrice:
  taxIncludedAmount:
    exclude: false
    exists: true
    equals: true
    isSimple: false
  dutyFreeAmount:
    exclude: false
    exists: true
    equals: true
    isSimple: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest to use :

```
public static JsonNode myMap;

myMap = mapper.readTree(new File("....yaml"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Jackson can parse YAML.

See here:

https://dzone.com/articles/read-yaml-in-java-with-jackson

Comment: i know how to parse yaml file, i was asking if theres a better way to represent my yaml so it will be easier to parse

Comment: Of course. That's what Jackson gives to you for free. You only need to define the bean representing the YAML file and you can serialize/deserialize it

Comment: @Sam You only need to create one class for the four properties `exclude`, `exists`, `equals` and `isSimple`. Then you can reuse it every entry. Or you just read it into an JsonObject tree.

Answer (score -2):

Some background (and opinion)
YAML is JSON for lazy people.
Because of this,
your YAML structure is basically a tree structure.
You may use Jackson to parse YAML the same way that you use Jackson to parse JSON;
create a POJO structure.

Here are some example classes for the "product" portion of your YAML:

```
public class TopClass
{
  private Product product;
}

public class Product
{
  private Blammy alternateId;
  private Blammy productId;
}

public class Blammy
{
  private boolean exclude;
  private boolean exists;
  private boolean equals;
  private boolean isSimple;
}
```

There are, figuratively,
a million sources available that describe how to use Jackson to parse JSON
(and probably YAML).
Here is a link to an existing StackOverflow question that discusses
[Parsing YAML with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53102500/parse-yaml-file-with-jackson)

Comment: thanks for your response. i was trying to figure out if there is a better way to represent my structure instead of like u said tree structure. maybe i should use my yaml differently something like
 productId: false, true, false, true
alternateId: true, false, false, true
etc etc...
or any other way so it will be easier to read and use it

Comment: Given the option, I never choose YAML.  I find a simple properties file to be easier to read.